# Hidden div on page load with Google ads and show hidden div with ads on element hover is it legal?

Tags: adsense

I have a gallery with hidden `div`, and if you hover over the gallery, the description will slide out on the right to show the image/video description, along a with Google Ad on the bottom. It's like Mashable and Huff gallery. My question is, is it legal? Am I breaking any TOS for the Google Adsense program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's legal, the only think you're doing is displaying it when a user hovers over a div. If you were deceiving the user, or something like that, it would be a different story.

Also, [here's the TOS to reference](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms).